# garbage text with c++ strings on send recv calls

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, c++11, networking

```
// In server.cpp after connection has established

std::string input;
input.reserve(5);
std::cout << "Enter message to send: ";

std::cin.ignore();  // =====(1)=====

std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
auto len        = input.length();

auto bytes_sent = send(newFD, input.data(), len, 0); // =====(2)=====

std::cout << "Input length : " << input.length() << std::endl
          << "Input bytes sent : " << bytes_sent << std::endl;
```

My aim is to use `std::string` instead of plain old `char[fixed]` in simple *tcp client server* program. So in `server.cpp` I have 2 doubts. So far my initial guesses are working as expected. I've marked them above in code.

1. `cin.ignore()` **vs** `cin.clear()` **+** `cin.sync()`
2. `std::string.data()` **vs** `std::string.c_str()`

Which should I use? I'm not even sure of the difference b/w any of these and I don't know if they're contributing to my problem.

---

```
// In client.cpp 

std::string message;
message.reserve(5);
auto len        = message.capacity();

auto bytes_recv = recv(sockFD, &message.front(), len - 1, 0);  // =====(1)=====

message[len] = 0; // =====(2)=====

close(sockFD);
freeaddrinfo(res);
std::cout << "Bytes recieved :" << bytes_recv << std::endl;

std::cout << message.c_str() << std::endl;  // =====(3)=====
```

---

And in client.cpp, everything goes wrong when I try to send bigger strings. But I probably know the cause, however solution is somewhat tricky to implement.

3. Am I doing right thing to pass `&std::string.front()` to write incoming data?
4. This is wrong, string class should manage this, right? However since I'm directly writing to `&front()`, I guess `length` won't get updated or I'm not sure what happens but data surely gets lost when outputting with `std::cout << message;`.
5. I'm doing this just because I'm directly writing to `&front`, still it produces garbage if somehow data returned is smaller than total length, probably because it cannot find terminating character at right place?

---

> **server.cpp**
>
> `// compile as 'g++ server.cpp -o server.app -std=c++14'`
>
> `// run as : './server.app 8080'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Run program as 'program port'" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    auto &portNum              = argv[1];
    const unsigned int backLog = 5;

    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

    int gAddRes = getaddrinfo(NULL, portNum, &hints, &res);
    if(gAddRes != 0) {
        std::cerr << gai_strerror(gAddRes) << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    std::cout << "Detecting addresses" << std::endl;

    unsigned int numOfAddr = 0;
    char ipStr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        std::string ipVer = "IPv0";

        if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            ipVer                    = "IPv4";
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr                     = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ++numOfAddr;
        }

        else {
            ipVer                     = "IPv6";
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr                      = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ++numOfAddr;
        }

        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipStr, sizeof(ipStr));
        std::cout << "(" << numOfAddr << ") " << ipVer << " : " << ipStr
                  << std::endl;
    }

    if(!numOfAddr) {
        std::cerr << "Found no host address to use" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter the number of host address to bind with:" << std::endl;
    unsigned int choice = 0;
    bool madeChoice     = false;
    do {
        std::cin >> choice;
        if(choice > (numOfAddr + 1) || choice < 1) {
            madeChoice = false;
            std::cout << "Wrong choice, try again!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            madeChoice = true;
    } while(!madeChoice);

    p           = res;
    bool isIPv4 = true;
    if(choice > 1) {
        unsigned int temp = 1;
        while(choice < temp) {
            p = p->ai_next;
            ++temp;
        }
        if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            isIPv4 = true;
        }
        else
            isIPv4 = false;
    }

    int sockFD = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
    if(sockFD == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error while creating socket" << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return -4;
    }

    int bindR = bind(sockFD, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
    if(bindR == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error while binding socket" << std::endl;
        close(sockFD);
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return -5;
    }

    int listenR = listen(sockFD, backLog);
    if(listenR == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error while Listening on socket" << std::endl;
        close(sockFD);
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return -6;
    }

    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    int newFD =
        accept(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
    if(newFD == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error while Accepting on socket" << std::endl;
        close(sockFD);
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return -7;
    }


    std::string input;
    input.reserve(5);
    std::cout << "Enter message to send: ";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
    auto len        = input.length();
    auto bytes_sent = send(newFD, input.data(), len, 0);
    std::cout << "Input length : " << input.length() << std::endl
              << "Input bytes sent : " << bytes_sent << std::endl;
    close(newFD);
    close(sockFD);
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

> **client.cpp**
>
> `// compile as 'g++ client.cpp -o client.app -std=c++14'`
>
> `// run as : './client.app 0 8080'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Run program as 'program ipaddress port'" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    auto &ipAddress = argv[1];
    auto &portNum   = argv[2];

    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

    int gAddRes = getaddrinfo(ipAddress, portNum, &hints, &res);
    if(gAddRes != 0) {
        std::cerr << gai_strerror(gAddRes) << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    std::cout << "Detecting addresses" << std::endl;

    unsigned int numOfAddr = 0;
    char ipStr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        std::string ipVer = "IPv0";

        if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            ipVer                    = "IPv4";
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr                     = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ++numOfAddr;
        }

        else {
            ipVer                     = "IPv6";
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr                      = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ++numOfAddr;
        }

        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipStr, sizeof(ipStr));
        std::cout << "(" << numOfAddr << ") " << ipVer << " : " << ipStr
                  << std::endl;
    }

    if(!numOfAddr) {
        std::cerr << "Found no host address to use" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter the number of host address to bind with:" << std::endl;
    unsigned int choice = 0;
    bool madeChoice     = false;
    do {
        std::cin >> choice;
        if(choice > (numOfAddr + 1) || choice < 1) {
            madeChoice = false;
            std::cout << "Wrong choice, try again!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            madeChoice = true;
    } while(!madeChoice);

    p           = res;
    bool isIPv4 = true;
    if(choice > 1) {
        unsigned int temp = 1;
        while(choice < temp) {
            p = p->ai_next;
            ++temp;
        }
        if(p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            isIPv4 = true;
        }
        else
            isIPv4 = false;
    }

    int sockFD = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
    if(sockFD == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error while creating socket" << std::endl;
        return -4;
    }

    int connectR = connect(sockFD, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
    if(connectR == -1) {
        close(sockFD);
        std::cerr << "Error while connecting socket" << std::endl;
        return -5;
    }

    std::string message;
    message.reserve(5);
    auto len        = message.capacity();
    auto bytes_recv = recv(sockFD, &message.front(), len - 1, 0);
    message[len] = 0;
    close(sockFD);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    std::cout << "Bytes recieved :" << bytes_recv << std::endl;
    std::cout << message.c_str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: atleast comment about why you're downvoting so I can improve my question rather than deleting and posting it again. I've provided minimal + runnable with no errors code examples as well as relevant code where I think I'm going wrong.

Comment: I guess you're being downvoted because you don't need all of this code to check how passing the address of `front` will behave.  All you need is a function that accepts a char*, write to it yourself using some hardcoded value, and see what the caller produces. No need for sockets or anything of the sort.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand what you're saying, but you've misunderstood me. I'm trying to write a socket program which involves using strings and hence `front()` call and not the other way around and then that is producing garbage text. I will eventually solve this problem on my own but getting help from someone who've already encountered such would save time.

Comment: You're not understanding my point.  Create a function that takes front().  In that function, you fill in with data.  Then see what the results are after you call this function.  There is no magical property in calling `send` or `recv` that makes std::string work differently.   I'm trying to make it simple for you to test your code by not introducing socket calls at all and all of that unnecessary boiler-plate code.

Comment: 'getting help from someone who've already encountered such would save time' - whose time  would be saved?

Comment: Without even bothering to look at the code, I'll guess that you have incorrectly and/or incompetely handled the result returned by recv().

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've already tried that and I've also checked the number of bytes being transferred is equal to number of bytes being received. If you'd see my points 3 & 4, I've mentioned that the problem resolves around writing data but not correctly being synced with length I guess? I've another working solution where I've made a vector<char> buffer and then appended all of them to a new string and printed that. But this is different.

Comment: ' probably because it cannot find terminating character at right place?' - TCP does not have terminating characters - it's an octet, (byte), stream.  The ONLY way you know how many chars have been loaded into your buffer, if any, is from the result returned by recv().

Comment: 'message[len] = 0;' will not work.  Neither will sundry combos of sizeof/strlen/whatever.  The result returned by recv() tells you the mumber of bytes loaded, nothing else does.

Comment: Also, avoid the use of 'message' at that level.  TCP cannot transfer messages longer than one byte and naming a stream buffer 'message' is likely to confuse and mislead.

Comment: @MartinJames `If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, the excess bytes shall be discarded.` this? But then I'm not sending too big strings. Let's try with `123456789`. Both `bytes_sent` as well as `bytes_recv` tell me it is 9 and output recieved on client side is - `123456789)�$�`

Comment: @MartinJames I'll make sure not to name that buffer as `message` in future.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal As the previous comment suggested, you should not be sticking 0 in your returned string.  The only thing you can use is the returned value from `recv`, and then shorten the std::string's size, respecting this value.  Hence, a `std::string` is **not** null-terminated.  The length of the data in a `std::string` is determined by `size()`.  A call to `std::string::resize()` will size the std::string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie see I'll try to summarize. There's no problem with man pages + textbook implementations of same program with `char[fixed size]`. However I'm trying to do this with string class. When I simply send `string.data()` and recieve it at other end, nothing gets printed. When I send `string.c_str()`, but this is exactly like sending char[] since that function returns const char[]. Then I tried sending `string.data()` as well as recieving to `string.front()`, if I print `string` directly, nothing gets printed, in case of `string.c_str()` garbage text gets printed.

Comment: However what's strange, the number of bytes is same at both ends. Niether am I sending so big that recv call will have to retrieve it in multiple calls that it gets lost. And nothing is actually getting lost, all data is present but with addition of garbage text. So my guess is `string` class isn't updating either size or something that it uses while printing?

Comment: `string` class isn't updating size because you've bypassed it's interface... you have to manually resize it (see my answer).

Comment: `recv` knows nothing about `std::string` and "updating string's size".  That function doesn't even know about C++ to be honest.  It is a C library function.  All of that resizing you're talking about has to be done "manually" on the string itself, and you're the only one that can do that.  If `recv` returns a value, then *you* have to size the string to that value.

Comment: Also, take a look at this simple example.  It is a fake `recv` function, and look at the results: http://ideone.com/veJQRJ  It uses `reserve`, just like your example.  But note the usage of `at()` to verify that there is a slot there in the string to place a character.  Boom -- runtime exception.  This is what I was referring to when I mentioned to create a function that mimics `recv` in a simple way.  You don't need mountains of socket code to test things.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your question on this is too vague to provide a helpful answer.
2. `data()` and `c_str()` are [effectively the same thing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) since C++11. It doesn't matter which one you use. **EDIT**: [In C++17, `data()` will have a non-`const` overload that returns a non-`const` `char*`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r1.html), so you will not need to do `&message.front()` to access a modifiable form of the underlying buffer. `c_str()` will remain `const`.
3. `&message.front()` is right... and wrong. That is the way to get a non-const `char*` to the contents of your `std::string`. BUT `message` is uninitialized and has a `size()` of `0` at that point in the code, so I'm not even sure that line of code is well-defined behavior. Rather than doing a `reserve(5)` I would construct your `string` like this: `auto message = std::string(5, ' ');` Then when you pass it into `recv` there will actually be valid stuff there for it to overwrite and you'll be able to read it from `message` afterwards.
4. Yes, this is wrong. You should be setting your string up to be the *actual* size you need. I suspect you can just pass in `len` instead of `len - 1` if you do this. On this topic, are you certain everything you'll ever receive is only 4 bytes long? Or are you intentionally only reading 4 bytes at a time?
5. a) you don't need to pass `c_str()` to `std::cout`. `<<` is overloaded to accept `std::string` as well. b) `recv` returns the number of bytes that you received. If that value is less than the size you initialized your `message` to, then the remaining characters in your string will be garbage (or `' '` `char`s if you followed my advice re:#3). I would do `message.resize(bytes_recv);` after receiving the message.

Comment: passing `len` instead of `len - 1` because of how `string` class handles end of string automatically? And yes I've intentionally set buffer size to 4 in this very example.

Comment: `std::string` keeps track of its own end, yes, so you don't need to make `len` longer than the message you will receive. Just make `len` the size of the message you will receive (or rather, the size of the maximum message length you'll accept) and then pass `len` to `recv` instead of passing `len - 1`. Don't forget to `resize(bytes_recv);` after receiving the message.

Comment: `data()` and `c_str()` are diverging again in c++17.

Comment: Can you give a concise reference? I see en.cppreference.com has added the change to their `std::string` reference, but it would be nice to be able to link to something more direct.

Answer (score 3):

Your questions have been addressed by caps,, but my 2 cents. What about having your own send/recv functions and hiding the complexity?

For example along the lines of:

```
ssize_t recv(int sockfd, std::string &buf, size_t len, int flags) {
    buf.resize(len);  // current status unknown -> make it fit
    ssize_t n = ::recv(sockfd, (void *)buf.data(), len, flags);
    buf.resize(n >= 0 ? n : 0);  // take error into account
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I have wrapper functions also. In my case I actually allocate a huge buffer and repeatedly call `recv` until it returns 0. It also checks for error codes and the like.